# Change MySQL query with button click or drop-down

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

I have a dropdown list being populated by the code below. I want to be able to change the **type = x** from a user input button(s) to predetermined options. I don't know if this is possible, especially without a page refresh as the drop-down is already populated from the initial query.

I need a dynamic query based on user selected without page refresh. Maybe I need to look at another language, such as Angular.

```
<?php
echo "<b>Start:<b/>";
echo "<select id='start' class=''>";

$list_query = mysqli_query($server, "SELECT `id`, `street`, `description`, `lat`, `lng`, `note`, `type` FROM `markers` WHERE `type` = 'red' ORDER BY `street`");
while($run_list = mysqli_fetch_array($list_query)){
    $u_id = $run_list['id'];
    $u_street = $run_list['street']; 
    $u_desc = $run_list['description'];  
    $u_note = $run_list['note'];  
    $u_type = $run_list['type'];  
    $u_lat = $run_list['lat'];   
    $u_lng = $run_list['lng'];  

    echo "<option value='$u_lat,$u_lng'>$u_street</option>";
}

echo "</select>";
?>
```

**Update**

The following returns "red" in the Div with ID of "callback". Instead of this how do I get this to update the query string?

Example Button:

```
<button id="b1" value="red" onclick="submit_1()">button 1</button>
```

Ajax:

```
function submit_1() {
var b1 = document.getElementById("b1").value;
console.log(b1);

var dataString = 'b1=' + b1;

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "php/getdata.php",
    data: dataString,
    cache: false,
    success: function(data) {
        $("#callback").html(data);
    }
});
}
```

Simple getdat.php:

```
<?php
$b1 = $_POST['b1'];

if ($b1 == "red") {
    echo $b1;
} else {
    echo 'Not '. $b1;
}
?>
```

Comment: why you don't use ajax?

Comment: its possible using ajax. How about you go read up, try something and post your code here. Then we can properly help you

Comment: @RafaelShkembi, That would be great but I am unsure on how to do this on the same page. Any examples?

Comment: you said that you use ajax to submit forms right?

Comment: make a ajax request to a file then in your ajax file make a variable and save all the values seperating by a coma. After saving the values in the var return a response with this variable from the ajax file. You have many many eaxaples just google

Comment: Does the updated ajax code help explain?

Answer (score 0):

Use AJAX. It's entirely possible with PHP and javascript. Basically, you can send off the choice with AJAX (onChange), use the "GET" method, and on success you return the HTML you want to replace (or the corresponding data, then change your HTML according to that).

**EDIT** Here is an example:

Basically you do some action and then call code like this:

```
$.ajax({
        url: <?php echo $your_action_url/user_choice;?>,
        type: 'GET',
        success: function(data) {
          $("#dropdown").replaceWith(data);
        }
      });
```

where the "data" is the dropdown information stored in a view page (I am using MVC in this particular example). Basically I am replacing the existing dropdown with a dropdown containing the right information. You would have the php function return the html that you want to replace the dropdown with.

Comment: I use Ajax for submitting forms using POST but I unsure on how what you are recommending works. Any tips or examples?

Answer (score 0):

add type in query string of request to server using Ajax.

```
$list_query = mysqli_query($server, "SELECT `id`, `street`,`description`, `lat`, `lng`, `note`, `type` FROM `markers` WHERE `type` =  $_GET['type'] ORDER BY `street`");
```

Comment: Without sanitisation that's really quite dangerous, and I don't think it solves the problem which is how to get the type back to PHP in the first place.

Comment: He said that he don't want to refresh the page

Answer (score 0):

try to learn ajax angular.js this library very simple use

http://phpenthusiast.com/blog/ajax-with-angular-and-php